# Flash AS3 Color Correction

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, colors

I will soon need a wig to replace the hair I've ripped out in regards to this problem! I  have a flash element on my website that is an XML gallery. It's supposed to blend seamlessly in with the background. I imported a PNG that has transparency which one edge is the blending edge with the other BG. Of course there's a color shift on both Mac and Windows. I tried importing PSD, saving as JPG, using GammaSlamma to remove profiling, all sorts of stuff.

I thought I was going to have to manually adjust the image to match and then serve two different Flash files depending on the user's OS or something crazy like that, but then I saw that AS3 supports color correction and a lot of people have seemed to find it useful. Needless to say I was very excited However, I've NEVER used AS3 before, and am developing a major headache over it.

I found a replacement free slideshow that's AS3 but I just have no idea where to add this code in.

Code that according to http://kelsocartography.com/blog/?tag=as3-color-correction is all that's needed:

```
stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
```

The code for the gallery (sorry for such a long snippet):

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  XMLSlideshow.as 
//  19 Feb 2009
//  www.simplistika.com
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.simplistika
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.Timer;

//Color correction
import flash.display.ColorCorrection;
stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  class definition
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class XMLSlideshow extends cXMLApp 
{
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  member data
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private var mTimer : Timer;
private var mPlaceholder1 : Loader = new Loader();
private var mPlaceholder2 : Loader = new Loader();
private var mControl : mcControl = new mcControl();
private var mSlide : int;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  slideshow setup
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private var mFile : String = "http://www.simplistika.com/files/ssp/Slideshow.xml";      // path to xml file
private var mInterval : uint = 8000;                                                    // slide interval

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  constructor
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public function 
XMLSlideshow(   
) : void
{       
    trace(this + " " + "XMLSlideshow.constructor");
    mTimer = new Timer(mInterval, 0);

    mPlaceholder1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, fOpen);
    mPlaceholder1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fResult);
    mPlaceholder2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, fOpen);
    mPlaceholder2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fResult);

    //this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fOnMouseOver);
    //this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fOnMouseOut);
    //this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fOnClick);
    mTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fTimer);

    addChild(mPlaceholder1);
    addChild(mPlaceholder2);
    addChild(mControl);

    mSlide = 0;
    mControl.btnForward.alpha = mControl.btnBack.alpha = mControl.btnPause.alpha = 0.0;
    //mControl.btnForward.buttonMode = mControl.btnBack.buttonMode = mControl.btnPause.buttonMode = true;
    mControl.btnForward.visible = mControl.btnBack.visible = false;

    super(mFile);   
    super.addEventListener("XMLLoaded", fStart);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fStart
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fStart(
    e : Event
) : void
{
    trace(this + " " + "XMLSlideshow.fStart");

    fLoadImage();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fOnMouseOver
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* private function 
fOnMouseOver(
e : MouseEvent
) : void 
{   

    switch (e.target.name)
    {
    case "btnPause":
        mTimer.running ? mControl.txtDesc.text = "Pause" : mControl.txtDesc.text = "Play";
        break;      
    case "btnForward":
        mControl.txtDesc.text = "Next";
        break;      
    case "btnBack":
        mControl.txtDesc.text = "Back";     
        break;  
    default:
        return;
    }
    mControl.txtDesc.alpha = 1;
    e.target.alpha = 0.7;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fOnMouseOut
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fOnMouseOut(
e : MouseEvent
) : void 
{
    switch (e.target.name)
    {
    case "btnPause":
    case "btnForward":
    case "btnBack":
        e.target.alpha = 0.5;
        mControl.txtDesc.alpha = 0;
        return;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fOnClick
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fOnClick(
    e : MouseEvent
) : void 
{
    trace(this + " " + "XMLSlideshow.fOnClick " + e.target.name);

    switch (e.target.name)
    {
    case "btnPause":
        if (mControl.txtDesc.text == "Pause") 
        {
            mTimer.stop();
            mControl.btnBack.visible = mControl.btnForward.visible = true;
            mControl.txtDesc.text = "Play";
        } 
        else 
        {
            mTimer.start();
            mControl.btnBack.visible = mControl.btnForward.visible = false;
            mControl.txtDesc.text = "Pause";
        }
        return;
    case "btnForward":
        mSlide == mItems - 1 ? mSlide = 0 : mSlide++;
        break;
    case "btnBack":
        mSlide == 0 ? mSlide = mItems - 1 : mSlide--;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }       
    fLoadImage();
} */

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fLoadImage
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fLoadImage(
) : void
{
    getChildIndex(mPlaceholder1) != 0 ?
        mPlaceholder2.load(new URLRequest(mData.slide[mSlide].url)) : 
            mPlaceholder1.load(new URLRequest(mData.slide[mSlide].url));
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fTimer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fTimer(
    e : TimerEvent
) : void
{
    mSlide == mItems - 1 ? mSlide = 0 : mSlide++;
    fLoadImage();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fOpen
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fOpen(
    e : Event
) : void 
{
    mTimer.stop();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fResult
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fResult(
    e : Event
) : void
{
    if (!mControl.btnForward.visible)
        mTimer.start();

    getChildIndex(mPlaceholder1) == 0 ? fNextImage(mPlaceholder1) : fNextImage(mPlaceholder2);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  fKenBurns
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function 
fNextImage(
    vPlaceholder : Loader
) : void
{
    setChildIndex(vPlaceholder, this.numChildren - 2);
    vPlaceholder.alpha = 0;
    vPlaceholder == mPlaceholder1 ? cTween.to(mPlaceholder2, {alpha:0}, 1) : cTween.to(mPlaceholder1, {alpha:0}, 1);
    cTween.to(vPlaceholder, { alpha:1 }, 1);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}   // class

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}   // package
```

You can see I added "color correction" in there, but get this error when I run the file:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable stage is not defined.
at global$init()
```

Any suggestions? Thank you....

Answer (score 2):

That's because the stage is not defined/created yet. So here are 2 options:

1. Use the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener to
   wait for the slideshow to be added
   to the stage. So you'd have add the
   following to the constructor:

   ```
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,
   ```

   _added);
        And add this function to the class:

   ```
   private _added function(e:Event)
   {
     removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,
   ```

   _added);
         stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
       }
2. Make a document class (see
   http://goo.gl/b92SU for a tut on
   these) for your flash like so:

   ```
   package
   {
     import flash.display.MovieClip;

     public class Main extends MovieClip
     {
       function Main()
       {
         addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _added);
         //other code that was in your main timeline
       }

       private function _added(e:Event):void
       {
         removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _added);
         stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry to be such a pain, but where would I add the first part? When I tried your #2, I got this error: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable stage is not defined.
 at com.simplistika::XMLSlideshow$cinit()
 at global$init()  -----  I added it underneath the "private var mSlide : int;" line.

Comment: Looks like the XMLSlideshow is getting made before the stage can be. I updated my answer on how to implement #1 in the class.

Comment: thanks. I think I got it to work via step 1 and it picks up the colorCorrection being added. But yet I still get the error: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ColorCorrection is not defined.
 at com.simplistika::XMLSlideshow/_added()  ---- I just don't understand why it's not seeing that ColorCorrection is not a variable!

Comment: Well if you don't need to make this a permanent addition to the class, I'd suggest using a document class to handle this. I updated #2 with details on this. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** put code outside a class. Remove the line

```
stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
```

And place it on your Document Class constructor. If you have trouble with that, means that your application is not properly set. I'd recommend you to create a new question, or read [this tutorial](http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2008/06/06/actionscript-30-documentclass-in-plain-english/).

Comment: do you mean put it inside the public function XMLSlideshow area? Even when I do that, I get the [object XMLSlideshow] XMLSlideshow.constructor
[object XMLSlideshow] cXMLApp.constructor
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ColorCorrection is not defined.
 at com.simplistika::XMLSlideshow() error.

Comment: Did you remove the import line?

Comment: I saw that there is a "import flash.display.*;" at the beginning of the file. So I removed "import flash.display.ColorCorrection" as I figured it was being imported already. Even when I went back in there and added it, I still get that error.